# Upload CSV using Parsecsv.php library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am new to this.

I have tried to use parsecsv for loading and parsing csv file in CodeIgniter. I copied the library to `applications/libraries` in the CodeIgniter directory. It seem to be working fine. My thing is that I am trying to get to see the contents of the csv file I upload in the view. I am having difficulty passing the variable contents to be viewed. Instead I am getting a an `Array()` on the screen and the name of the file I uploaded. but I need to see the contents of the load file in the view.
like:

```
first name: james
last name: brown
id: 01
age: 12
date of entry: 01/01/02
```

I hope this is clear. Any ideas on how to pass the contents of Controller as an array or object to be vieed on a browser? Just remember we have only have controller and the View, of course we also have the `parsecsv.php` load to the libraries folder. Any answers will be appreciated. thanks

Below is the controller Code.

```
<?php
class Csvparser extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('parseCSV');
    }

    function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('limit');
    }    
}
```

Also this is the code to help display the code in regular php

```
<?php
# include parseCSV class.
require_once('../parsecsv.lib.php');

$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->sort_by = 'rating';

$csv->offset = 2;
# limit the number of returned rows.
$csv->limit = 10;
?>
```

Looking at the Controller code above and the regular PHP code pasted, how would I be able to pass these objects over to the View so I can see them in a browser?

Any and all the help is very much appreciated.

Comment: your problem is the parsing of the file or the exibition of its content in some view?

Comment: I am using ParseCSV as a library in CodeIgniter and I am having difficulty exibiting the contents of the csv file on the VIEW (exibiting the contents in the View). In regular PHP it works fine using the below code.

Comment: can you show us the code of your code igniter controller and view? what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is actually downloadable here.  https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/downloads/detail?name=parsecsv-0.4.3-beta.zip&can=2&q= and the name is parsecsv-0.4.30-beta.zip.

Comment: This is the code I use to display it <code><?php
# include parseCSV class.
require_once('../parsecsv.lib.php');

$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->sort_by = 'rating';

$csv->offset = 2;
# limit the number of returned rows.
$csv->limit = 10;
?></code>

Comment: It works perfect in regular PHP, but I am challenged when I try to use the Controller and View in CI.

Comment: below is the Controller code;